# Impersonate User with Salesforce as Identity Provider (WS-Federation)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, salesforce, single-sign-on, saml, ws-federation

**What we have**

We currently have a customer system as a ASP.NET MVC website.
SSO authentication is handled via WS-Federation with Salesforce as the Identity Provider.

Currently, everything works as expected. Users log in via the SF community login and are redirected to the website. The .net Identity has all the expected claims that we can query to check the users access to pages, tools etc.

**What we need**

The client has recently requested that they want the ability for their customer support team to be able to "impersonate" an existing user and thus "see" the website as the customer does.
We've looked at other options (screen sharing, separate admin site etc) but the customer ideally wants their support staff to see the site as the customer.

**What I've looked at**

Trawling through the SF documentation I saw that you can log into SF as other users if you're an admin (and it's set up to do so). This worked in SF as expected and because SF is the identity provider for SSO, I thought maybe I could then visit the website as that user - but no - I was challenged for username and password.

I'm no expert on Salesforce, WS-Fed, SAML, OWIN, SSO etc. and the people that created the solution no longer work here (and neither does the company that setup and APEX WS-Fed implementation for the client...).

**Advice?**

So, is this even possible?
If so, is there any articles, documentation, examples anywhere?

Thanks muchly.

Comment: 1: SF does not support WS-Fed out of the box. 2: Out of the box, impersonation in SF ("login as...") does not extend to SSO, this is by design. What you're after is possible with a sizeable amount of custom code, we've done this for clients.

Comment: thanks for the comment @identigral. Salesforce has already been set up with custom APEX endpoints to handle this. So SSO is currently working as intended.

We're currently looking at various ways to meet our clients request to allow their support staff to help their customers when they have issues. And they liked the sound of "impersonation" as it would allow their support staff to see the site exactly like their customer would.

Sounds like I need to do more research. Thanks